# Can Python recognize and print out everytime a word is used in an entered prompt?

Tags: python

```
#Color import
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

#Entry Prompt Guiding Person What to Do
("\n")
print(Fore.GREEN + "Copy Your User Agreement \n")

print("Paste It Into Search Engine Search Bar \n")

print("Copy The Text Pasted Into Search Bar \n")

entryPrompt = str(input("Paste Here:",))

#Splits code into words

words = entryPrompt.split(" ")

#Tells program to print out where it finds the key phrase and the first 20 words before and 20 words after. I need it to recognize every time the phrase is identified and print out the 20 words before and after instead of just the first time it identifies it.
try:
   findTPA = words.index("third-party")
   print("\n")
   print(Fore.CYAN + " ..." + " ".join(words[findTPA-20:findTPA+19]) + "... ")
   print("\n")

#Tells program what to do if it does not find the phrase
except ValueError:
    print("\n")
    print(Fore.RED + "No third-party agreement present")
    print("\n")


input("Press Enter to exit...")
```

Does anyone know a way I can get this to recognize everytime the key phrase "third-party" is recognized and not just the first time it is?

Comment: Loop over the list, checking each word to see if it's a match.

Comment: you can get all the indexes with `findTPA = [i for i, word in enumerate(words) if word == 'third-party']`

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the whole list checking for the word:

```
for i, word in words:
    if word == 'third-party':
        start = max(i-20, 0) # avoid negative start index
        end = i + 19
        print(f'\n{Fore.CYAN} ...{" ".join(words[start:end])}...\n")
```